# Last Modified Date of a File

Tags: javascript

So...On my page I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(document.lastModified);
</script>
```

This displays the last modified date of my webpages index.html.

I now want to display the last modified date of another file on my server. How do I do this?

I tried:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
myActiveXObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
file = myActiveXObject.GetFile("My File.xlsx");
document.write(file.DateLastModified);
// -->
```

However it shows a bogus last modified date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MDN page about `document.lastModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.lastModified) states that the property is "not part of any standard", so I'm not sure it will be reliable across all browsers.  The [MSDN article on the lastModified property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533946%28VS.85%29.aspx)  says the same thing.

I think the only reliable way to get the last modified date of an arbitrary file is on the server side.

Comment: Safari 5 does not implement document.lastModified.

Comment: @kennebec: Safari 5.1.1 (Win) does.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
      $url = 'URL LINK OF WEB PAGE';

      echo ("<pre>");
      $a= (get_headers($url,1));

      $c =$a['Last-Modified'];
      echo ("<p>");
      print_r ($c);

?>
```

This is the PHP sentence that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't without making another request via AJAX via the web server.